# Using Node to call SOAP Web Service over https

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I am trying to use node-soap https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap to call a web service but I am having trouble using the module with **https**.

In the code below I am using **http** and I can see the functions and log a `describe()` of the `About` function. (Responses are empty, probably because the WS is setup like that when using http(?))

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = "http://XXXXX/service.svc?DocArchiveService/DocArchiveV201409";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("USERXXX" + ":" + "PWYYY").toString("base64");

var args = {};

soap.createClient(url, { wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {

    console.log(client.describe().DocArchiveV201409.DocArchiveV201409Soap.About);

    client.DocArchiveV201409.DocArchiveV201409Soap.About(args, function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
{ input: {}, output: { AboutResult: 's:string' } }
```

Error message (this is fine since the response will be empty anyway):

> Error: Cannot parse response
>       at finish (E:\Qlikview\SourceDocuments\UnderDevelopment\Node\node_modules\so
>   ap\lib\client.js:383:19)

**My problem is that when using https I get an undefined client.**

> E:\Qlikview\SourceDocuments\UnderDevelopment\Node\Soap.js:23
>   console.log(client);
>               ^ ReferenceError: client is not defined
>       at Object.anonymous (E:\Qlikview\SourceDocuments\UnderDevelopment\Node\Soa p.js:23:13)

Have anyone used node-soap with https?

**edit:**
As the result below suggests I need to have the certificate first. I have tried using SoapUI without the cert and that works fine. Maybe there is some parameters to `createClient` I can use in node-soap?

console.log(err) returns:

```
{ Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1079:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_IS
SUER_CERT_LOCALLY' }
```

Comment: Try to print `err`  in case of `https`. `console.log(err)`

Comment: @MukeshSharma That returns: { Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1079:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_IS
SUER_CERT_LOCALLY' }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As cleared from `tls` specific error, you aren't able to create soap client
by invoking `soap.createClient`. It is returning `err` and `undefined` client, that's why subsequent calls are failing.

The main reason behind the `certificate` issue can be either soap server certificates are signed by `internal CA` or soap server is using `self-signed certificate`.

Possible solutions that can be used to tackle the issue are

1. [ Not recommended ] Ignore certificate specific warnings by disabling `SSL` check at request time. 
   e.g.

   ```
   var request = require('request');
   var specialRequest = request.defaults({
      strictSSL: false
   });
   ```
2. [ Recommended ] Provide root/intermediate certificates of CA to verify the remote certificates.

   ```
   var request = require('request');
   var specialRequest = request.defaults({
      agentOptions: {
         ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.cert.pem') //path of CA cert file
      }
   );
   ```

For both solutions, pass this `specialRequest` to `createClient`.

```
    soap.createClient(url, { 
        wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth},
        request : specialRequest
    }, function(err, client) {
        //your code
    });
```

I just went through the documentation and came up with the solution. It may or may not work, but worth trying logically. I couldn't test above-mentioned solutions, but it should work.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your not recommended solution and that works. I will look into providing the certificates.

Answer (score 4):

For recommended solution - Provide root/intermediate certificates of CA to verify the remote certificates, try this-

```
var request = require('request'); 
var specialRequest = request.defaults({ ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.cert.pem') //path of CA cert file );

var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer.from("myUsername:myPassword").toString("base64"); 
var options = { wsdl_headers: { Authorization: auth }, request: specialRequest };

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
    client.myFunction(args, function (err, result) { 
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```